# login form of web service is returning null session_id

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-services

i am working with a we applications that should get data from a web service and then show the data in a telerik grid. I have wrote all the code to get the data from the web service but in some point i can not go further because i have problems with the login method that is not returning the session_id as it should.

```
        private string login_f()
    {
        string username = "WebServiceC";

       deltaServer service = new deltaServer();

        string password = "111111111111111111111111";
        string session_id = service.LOGIN(username, password, "dr", "NON");

        return session_id;
    }
```

above is the code of my login method.

```
    public string LOGIN([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] 
        string USERNAME, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] 
        string PASSWORD, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] 
        string LANGUAGE, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] 
        string CHANNEL)
    {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("LOGIN", new object[] {
                    USERNAME,
                    PASSWORD,
                    LANGUAGE,
                    CHANNEL});
        return ((string)(results[0]));
    }
```

and this is the code of the Login from my Reference.cs file. The strange thing is that in other places of my application this works fine. In this case the session_id returns NULL.
Any idea where i am doing wrong and how to fix this? I will appreciate every answer since i am stuck for 2 days with this

Comment: The method is not returning or your client is getting null?
If you put a breakpoint in "return session_id", you can see the value? or in this point it is already empty?

Comment: How many items you have in results, in the point you return the first position?

Comment: Careful with returning the first position of your results, if no data is returned from your Invoke, you will receive a Index out of bound error